# Match and reference column on a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I know how to get the column number a certain value is found at in a different sheet:

```
=MATCH($B$4;Sheet1!1:1;0)
```

I know how to e.g. count how many non-empty cells there are in a column on a different sheet:

```
=COUNTA(Sheet1!$AA:$AA)
```

Is there any way to combine the two to count how many non-empty cells there is in a column which contains a certain value, on a different sheet, without resorting to UDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer (sort of) from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18377828/4497791).

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$ZZ;0;MATCH($B3;Sheet1!$1:$1;0)))
```

I'd have liked the array used in the index formula to be arbitrarily big (i.e. take into account the whole spreadsheet, ignoring potential changes to the number of columns, etc.), but I suppose I can hardcode its bounds too.

Learning that I can use 0 as the second argument of `index` to return the whole column was really helpful :)